# Query a listValue in an Entity using Google Datastore API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible to query a listValue from an Entity using the [Google Cloud Datastore API](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/datasets/runQuery).

For example if I had a Post Entity for a blog:

```
[
  {
    "title": "My First Post",
    "tags": ["google", "android"]
  },
  {
    "title": "My Second Post",
    "tags": ["google"]
  }
]
```

Obviously the data above would be tag properly (e.g. with listValue, stringValue etc). Can a query be made to give me all Post entities who have a tag that equals "android".

I've tried several things with no success. Both Standard and GQL queries. I've even tried to apply some GQL queries that would normally work when using Datastore from a Google App Engine instance(python) but they don't seem to work with [Google Cloud Datastore API](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/datasets/runQuery).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure this "tag" property is indexed.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin yup it's indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I started debugging this morning and discovered that the filter that was being sent was undefined.

You always miss stuff like that during late night coding sessions.